# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/images/logo.png" and the CSS changes are applicable on UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am facing an issue in look and feel of my static assets

my application.css looks

```
*= home
 *= bootstrap.min
 *= bootstrap-theme
 *= bootstrap-sprockets
 *= bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

application.js looks

```
//= require google-map
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you call somewhere this `logo.png`, try to grep it

Comment: @mechnicov Thank you  I tried helper.assets_path("logo"), this solved image path not found problem. fontawesom.webfont still exist